# GET method status is 401, but headers satisfy request headers (Postman)

Tags: json, get, postman

I am trying to make an app that represents a web page, currently i have an account in web page an through my account i can access site and know all request headers and etc. So my first step is to make a simulation in postman to get information that i will display in my application.

1. I need to get a token to access other information.
   [image]
   Using post method i get two tokens
2. To get other information i will only need master token, so i am trying to get that information. Image below shows request  headers
   [image]
3. When i type all headers in postman using get method, i get 401 (Unauthorized) that means site did not give me json, because i didin't gave autorization token. 
   [image]
   but i clearly gave authorization token as you can see in image above.

Thanks for any suggestions how to fix my problem.

Comment: Don't ask questions about the REST interface of an unknown third party software system.

Comment: ok, i deleted rest tag

Answer (score 0):

`Authorization` field follows the below syntax:

```
Authorization: <type> <credentials>
```

Where `<type>` is the authentication scheme in use. Make sure you provide the correct value, referring to [IANA registry of Authentication schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml).

Answer (score 0):

In your "Authorization" parameter, try adding "Bearer " before the token (note the space after "Bearer "

[image]

Comment: I added Bearer in front of token like in your example, but response is 401 (Unauthorized). Still thanks for your suggestion!